# Rounding and "Double.valueOf with float"

Tags: java, double, floating-point-precision, value-of

In Java 6 there are only two Double#valueOf methods :
`Double#valueOf(double)` and `Double#valueOf(String)`.

1 - Witch method is calling when I execute `Double#valueOf(float)` ?

According to Javadoc, it seems to be `Double#valueOf(String)` but Eclipse links with `Double#valueOf(double)`.

2 - Why there is these differents ?

Calling `Double.valueOf` with float round the result :

```
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(0.63F));  // displays 0.6299999952316284
```

Whereas

```
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(0.63F)));  // displays 0.63
```

**Extract from javadoc** (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) :

`the float literal 0.1f is equal to the double value 0.10000000149011612`

and

string in param `is regarded as representing an exact decimal value in the usual "computerized scientific notation" or as an exact hexadecimal value; this exact numerical value is then conceptually converted to an "infinitely precise" binary value that is then rounded to type double by the usual round-to-nearest rule of IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic`

Comment: "According to Javadoc, it seems to be Double#valueOf(String)" <-- where did you read that? This is not how I read the javadoc at all...

Comment: I did not read it explicitly, but the  Double#valueOf(double) javadoc provides not much information and don't talk about the representation of float ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to Javadoc, it seems to be `Double#valueOf(String)` but Eclipse links with `Double#valueOf(double)`.

I couldn't find the place in Javadoc where it would suggest that the `String` overload would get called in this situation, but Eclipse is right: there is no implicit conversion from `float` to `String`, but there is an implicit conversion from `float` to `double`, so `Double#valueOf(double)` is the correct overload.

> Calling Double.valueOf with float round the result

It does not "round" the result, it changes its representation to fit `double`, which has higher precision. However, neither `float` nor `double` could represent `0.1` exactly, because it cannot be represented as a sum of negative powers of `2`. If you use `0.25` instead of `0.1`, this would not happen, because `0.25` is `2 ^ -2`, and therefore can be represented precisely in both `float` and `double`.

Comment: I suspected there was a notion of representation. Thank you for this detailed explanation